# Set IPython Qt Console start up location in WinPython

Tags: python, ipython

I was wondering that would anyone please help me in setting up the IPython Qt Console start up location in WinPython? I think the way to do it in ipython is to modify the ipy_user_conf.py and add in os.chdir(my_path), however I could not find ipy_user_conf.py in WinPython.

Thanks a lot!

-Shawn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Locating configuration files](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/development/config.html#locating-these-files)

```
$ ipython locate
```

[Startup files documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/development/config.html#startup-files)

> If you want some code to be run at the beginning of every IPython session with a particular profile, the easiest way is to add Python (.py) or IPython (.ipy) scripts to your <profile>/startup directory.

Comment: Links are broken. Can you fix them?